# can we send the same analytics event to 2 different google analytics accounts?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I m the editor of a white-labeled app, and I would like to let my client access his analytics data, but I would like also to include his analytics data in my global analytics account (where I want to merge the analytics data of all my clients). So for this, I must be able to send from the app the analytics data to 2 different accounts (the account of the client, and my account). Is it possible ?

Comment: probably not with the default sdks, but you could call the api endpoints directly or make a second copy of the sdk and modify it to use another config file. make sure the users and your clients are both aware of this extra data collection, might get you in a lot of legal trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.  An app can only collect information for itself, stored in a single project.  You can always export that data to BigQuery and do whatever you want with it, but it won't be visible in any other Firebase project console.